# Google markers Start not clickable

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Hey all i have the following code here: http://jsfiddle.net/DDT4p/

That demonstrates that "B" is clickable while "A" is not. I am not finding in code why this is the case since they both use the same code with differences in destination names (start, dest)

If anyone can spot the cause of this then please let me know :o)

**The code to fix it was in this:**

```
var imageStart = new     
google.maps.MarkerImage('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenA.png', 
new google.maps.Size(42,25), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0,25));
```

I had the incorrect points! Thanks to Andrew and GHz for pointing that out.

Comment: It's not the same code. The clickable area defined by `shapeStart` is very different from that defined by `shapeDest`. I'd also suggest using *your* markers, not Google's. Odd things can happen if your clickable area is outside the marker icon. It's obvious that your intended icons are not those in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours:

```
var imageStart = new 
google.maps.MarkerImage('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_greenA.png',
new google.maps.Size(68, 40), **new google.maps.Size(42,25),** new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
new google.maps.Point(0,25));`
```

Remove the second "size" parameter and it will work...

:)

Comment: Ah yes, i was about to post that from what Andrew said above.